# .htaccess deny php files from all except index

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE on
    RewriteBase /wsproject/

    Options All -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to hide everything from the users: the directory structure and private files, while enable public files: *.js, *.html, *.css, *.swf, *.jpg and other stuff. I want .php files to be accessible only from the file system, except only the index.php in the root dir.

I only want to serve request via HTTP which are written with an (abstract) MVC URL pattern like: `www.domain.com/lang/controller_name/action_name/arg1/arg2/././argn`, which are being rewritten by .htaccess, and public *.html, *.js ...etc files.

While `Options All -Indexes` hides file listing, it will not prevent an undesirable request e.g.: `www.domain.com/library/Bootstrap.php` from being served.
Whereas deleting/commenting out `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` would solve this, but in this case none of my public .html, .css, .js ...etc files would be served.

I tried to apply Deny from all for each php files except the index.php but I always get an 500-internal server error message. Im doing this on localhost, on windows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of stating that all but existing files should be directed to index.php, you can say that everything except *.js, *.html, *.css, *.swf, *.jpg should be directed to index.php.

This isn't exactly the same as denying, since you don't give a Forbidden response. Though in this case you don't give out any information about which files exist or not, so I'd argue that it's a better solution.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE on
    RewriteBase /wsproject/

    Options All -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteRule \.(js|html|css|swf|jpg)(\?|$) - [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^index.php(\?|$) - [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that rewriting to `-`, means no rewriting is done at all.

Comment: This worked well for me when the above solutions did not - slight modifications for those that try it:

Remove RewriteBase if you don't need it
Add some additional RewriteRule exceptions for Folders / Files if necessary, like so:

`RewriteRule ^administrator - [QSA,L]`
`RewriteRule \.(js|html|css|swf|jpg|ico|eot|woff|ttf|svg)(\?|$) - [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than (or maybe as well as...) editing your .htaccess file, I'd suggest using the `chmod` command to modify the read/write/executability values of your files.

A relatively succinct and sensible explanation of what `chmod` is/does can be found [in the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473104/chmod-for-php-web-application), but generally the simplest way is to `chmod 644` your files and `chmod 755` your folders.